# How to typecast from var to an object

Tags: c#, linq

i just linq to find the max object from a list of object now i want change it back from var to object. How is that done.

```
List < MyObject> lt = matchings.ToList();
var wwe = lt.Max(ya => ya.Similarity);
var itemsMax = lt.Where(xa => xa.Similarity == wwe);
MyObject sm =(TemplateMatch) itemsMax;//it gives error here
```

Comment: How does matchings, MyObject and TemplateMatch look? Guess you could simplify your algorithm a bit.

Comment: a) your life will improve if you stop using var.  b) mixing generics and casting is a code smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lt.Where` returns an enumerable. So, that's why it does not cast to a single object. Add a `.Single()` method on the end and it should cast.

Answer (score 9):

`var` is not a type. It's a keyword meaning "fill in the type for me".

`Where` returns a collection. You are attempting to cast a collection to a single item.

Instead of `Where`, use `FirstOrDefault`.

```
var itemsMax = lt.FirstOrDefault(xa => xa.Similarity == wwe);
```

Now you get back a single item, and can cast it if needed.

Note the above works if you only want a single item with that value.

If it is possible to have multiple items with the max value--and you want multiple items back--combine `Where` with `OfType` or `Cast`.

```
var itemsMax = lt.Where(xa => xa.Similarity == wwe); 
var allItemsCasted = itemsMax.Cast<NewType>(); // this throws
var typeCompatibleItems = itemsMax.OfType<NewType>(); // this filters
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that `Where` returns a collection of objects, but you need only a single object. Try `itemsMax.Single()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enumerating through the `matchings` twice (once to calculate the "max similarity" and a second time to find the item that has the max similarity), you could do this in one pass using `IEnumerable<T>.Aggregate`:

```
var sm = matchings.Aggregate((maxItem, next) => 
            next.Similarity > maxItem.Similarity ? next : maxItem);
```